# How does one create a php-stream from a file descriptor in a PHP extension?

Tags: php, c, php-extension

I have a library that returns a file descriptor when a file is opened and I would like to pass it to the calling PHP script as a `php_stream`. Looking around, I don't see an easy way to create a `php_stream` and have it use the file stream from the descriptor.

Is there an easy way of doing this, and if not, how does one create a `php_stream` from scratch with the descriptor or a `FILE*` instance?

Comment: Look into php_stream_fopen_from_fd

Comment: Please refer to this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php